# Disabling proxy repositories in Nexus OSS 3.1.0

Tags: maven, nexus

I'm trying to set up a new small Nexus OSS server. Nexus ships with proxies set up for the Apache, Central, and Codehaus repositories, assuming that the Nexus server will be local to the users. I don't want to send all of my artifacts through it. What's the best way to stop Nexus from proxying external repositories--should I just delete the entries for them?

I have gone through [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/538556/disabling-proxy-repositories-in-nexus) question. But the nexus OSS 3.0.1 UI looks very different. I am not able to find the option "Put out of service" in the UI shown below:-

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in [nexus community](https://groups.google.com/a/glists.sonatype.com/forum/#!topic/nexus-users/mEjJqw_9AcY) it is represented as a checkbox instead, labeled **Online**.

[image]